# Find overlapping date-range records with Mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql, date-range, mysql-5.6

I have a list of events with date-range and venue id.
I need to find the max count of distinct active venues at the same time.

```
create table if not exists events
(
    eventstart datetime,
    eventend datetime,
    venue int
);

INSERT INTO events VALUES ('2022-04-06 18:00:00', '2022-04-06 19:30:00', 1);
INSERT INTO events VALUES ('2022-04-06 18:15:00', '2022-04-06 21:00:00', 1);
INSERT INTO events VALUES ('2022-04-06 18:45:00', '2022-04-06 20:00:00', 2);
INSERT INTO events VALUES ('2022-04-06 18:30:00', '2022-04-06 19:00:00', 3);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a2PRXG2WQ3samrWb66fimv/4

With the previous example, I expect a result of 3 because from 18.45-19.00 there 3 concurrent distinct venues active at the same time.

I cannot find a smart way to write this query.

Comment: Join where eventstart or eventend is in between the other values, did you try that?

Comment: I'm missing something: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aUABkPRSD9g5JP2esYZ5rQ/1

Comment: I'm not sure how mysql handles this, only mssql. But it looks like between does not work on your specific columns. It might be due to the format, might be due to other things. But do not distrust, you can always use >= operators instead and go about it that way.

Comment: I've done a fiddle, but I want you to tell me how you want it to filter just 4. At some point or another all 4 of these overlap. Do you want to select WHERE it overlaps yourself or what? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aUABkPRSD9g5JP2esYZ5rQ/4 my fiddle

Comment: 1st row overlaps with 2 and 3 (Since eventend is before the other events have stopped). 2nd row overlaps with 1,3,4. 3rd row overlaps with 1,2,4. 4th row overlaps with 1,2,3.
According to this - venue 1 has an event going on at the same time, since at 19:00. Both row 1 and 2 are active there.

Comment: I set the second row on porpuse in my example because I want the max DISTINCT count of venues active at the same time. Maybe I can split the problem, find all overlapping date-range with the venues IDS and then distinct venue IDS in this subset and finally find the MAX count.

Comment: @Stoff your fiddle gives always the full table